# How can I get UIView's (x, y) when using AutoLayout if initial frame was misconfigured?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, coordinates, frame

Perhaps it is a misuse of a `UIView`'s `frame` property by my setup code, for auto laid-out views, wherein, because I assume the view's initial `frame` property values won't matter once AutoLayout constraints are added, that I can use the `frame.origin` to cache  values that aren't really the view's origin in coordinate space.

What I mean by "misusing" the frame property is: I am setting the `frame.origin` to values to be parameter values in my constraint setup function calls, because I like like the succinctness and convenience for tweaking constraint offsets by the CGRect, in my code. But perhaps it's backfiring? Not sure why though...

For example:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftSideView.trailingAnchor, 
                                  constant: view.frame.origin.x)
    .
    .
    .
])
```

Initially it seems fine, views are placed as expected on the screen, but after views have been laid-out by AutoLayout, the `frame.origin` seems to reflect the original misappropriation by me... E.g. after AutoLayout `frame.origin` is still (10, 10)... anyway after AutoLayout, `frame.origin` are *not* the correct absolute values in the coordinate system one generally refers to the frame property to get.

After I do this:

```
 view.setNeedLayout()
 view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

When I print the frame.origin values, they aren't the view's actual position.

Why wouldn't they be?
So, how can I find the right values?

Perhaps I need to call one of UIView's superview coordinate translation functions?

*UPDATE: The view that is not having its origin set is actually the leftSideView, which I configured using the same approach as the view I'm constraining. I did run setNeedsLayout()/layout, but now I'm thinking that AutoLayout doesn't have enough data yet to calculate the frame so I have a chicken-egg problem where I'm trying to add constraints based on constraints that are unresolved yet, which won't work.*

Comment: So just to be clear, you are trying to get the frame of the view after layout, but it still remains  (10, 10, 100, 100) for some reason?

Comment: Yes. And I virtually re-wrote the question yet again to try to prune it and make it clearer. I'll stop now. Anyway, you get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong view to layout. There is nothing much for `view` to layout, other than its own size. It doesn't know how to lay itself out relative to `leftSideView`, because `leftSideView` is not one of its subviews.

To layout `view` relative to `leftSideView`, find their common parent, and ask *it* to layout. Suppose `view.superview` is the common parent, do:

```
view.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Then `view.frame` will be the values you'd expect.

Alternatively, you can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in `UIViewController` or `layoutSubviews` in the common parent of the views you want to layout, to detect when layout has finished, without calling `layoutIfNeeded`. In there, `frame` will have the correct values too.

Minimal example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let v = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(v)
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            v.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 30),
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
        let u = UIView(frame: .init(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.addSubview(u)
        u.backgroundColor = .red
        u.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            u.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            u.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leftAnchor),
            u.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            u.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
        
        // before any layout
        print(u.frame)

        // laying out u, doesn't change anything
        u.layoutIfNeeded()
        // note that the above could change the frame of u depending on the frame 
        // of u and its size constraints, but I've deliberately chosen these
        // values and constraints so that it matches your behaviour
        print(u.frame)

        // laying out u, and v, making u.frame what you expect
        view.layoutIfNeeded() // view is the common parent between u and v
        print(u.frame)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I see what you're saying, and that is a good idea. I added an update to my question, to provide more context. The *real* issue is that I'm trying to center a view between right and left views.  The centering sort of works but not quite. Depending on the simulated iPhone device, and the screen width it is appearing centered in one device type's width, but off-center in another's. So I wanted to constrain the view I'm centering based on the positions of the views to the right and left of it, which is a chicken-egg problem.

Comment: I'm using two 'spacer' views for the centering. I'm thinking now of first constraining everything, and then using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to pick up the actual placement of left and right views, and then tweaking the constant of the view I'm centering based on a runtime calculation.

Comment: @clearlight How about putting a view (let's call this the "container") in between the left and right views, with container.left = leftView.right and container.right = rightView.left. Then, you can center your view inside the container by doing view.centerX = container.centerX plus other constraints for y position and size. You shouldn't need to do any runtime calculation for this.